# custom TextView not wrapped in table layout

Tags: android

I have created a custom textview and want to add it dynamically to a table layout:

**custome textview code named custom_table_cell :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/style_table_cell"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Cell" >

</TextView>
```

**My activity code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flight" >

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblInvoiceData"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

**and my code to add table row to table layout :**

```
public TextView TableGetCell(Context context, String Text, int ColumnId) {
        final TextView cell = (TextView) ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_table_cell,
                null);
        cell.setText(Text);

        cell.setTypeface(Graphic.GetFontFaceFarsi(context));

        cell.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(ColumnId));

        return cell;
    }

public void CreateRows() {
        for (final Customer d : Customers) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

            tr.addView(TableGetCell(this, String.valueOf(d.Name), 0));
            tr.addView(TableGetCell(this, String.valueOf(d.Family), 0));
            tr.addView(TableGetCell(this, String.valueOf(d.Age), 0));

            tblInvoiceData.addView(tr);
        }

    }
```

and my question : why text view not wrapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
row.setLayoutParams(lp);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
textView.setText("yourValue");
row.addView(textView);
tablelayout.addView(row);
```